# DC Gain of the System

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, feedback, gain, compensation

I'm trying to design a feedbcak loop compensator and I'm following the instructions on power supply cookbook.

Book has calculations for DC gain like equations below:
[image]

in my situation Vin: 40V-60V and Vout:350V, Nsec/Npri:10 (full-bridge)

DC gain becomes 350V/40V: 8.75 and that means peak to peak output voltage of the error amplifier is: 45.7V

question is what is this peak to peak output voltage of the error amplifier? what do we use it for?

bonus question: I'm using sg3525 and I can't find the ramp voltage of it, is there a calculation for it? Here is the datasheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sg3525.pdf

thank you.

Comment: There are a lot more steps byond just calculating Adc... Usually Adc is used along with the error amplifier gain (60db for your chip) in a few calculations.

Comment: The expression you give is quite strange, where did you get it? Also, what is the converter topology for which you need to plot the ac response?

Comment: @VerbalKint I got them from power supply cookbook, it is a full bridge dc-dc converter.

Comment: Not sure what cookbook is this? A full-bridge dc-dc converter is a buck-derived topology whose transfer function is that of a forward converter. Is this a voltage- or current-mode control? Let me know and I'll write an answer.

Comment: It's marty brown's cookbook page 202, I'm trying to build a full bridge dc-dc converter with voltage mode control @VerbalKint

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need to stabilize your converter is the *control-to-output* transfer function: if a *stimulus* is applied to the duty ratio input, how does it propagate through the converter and create a *response* on the output. You can obtain this transfer function in various ways, for instance via a small-signal model like the PWM switch model or by using a piece-wise linear simulator like SIMPLIS. The program lets you simulate a switching circuit (and thus observe the cycle-by-cycle waveforms) and delivers the ac response later on after a few seconds.

The below circuit shows a possible example running with Elements, the free demonstration version:

[image]

This is a 5-V/100-A full-bridge converter operated in voltage-mode control from a 24-V dc source. The circuit is simplified to let you run it on Elements but a real application would require additional protection circuits like peak current limit for instance. If you run this circuit, you obtain the below transient waveforms confirming the 5-V output:

[image]

The control-to-output transfer function is immediate and shows a dc gain of 11.1 dB with the classical second-order response of a buck-derived topology:

[image]

If you want to determine the dc gain analytically, it is that of a forward converter:

[image]

In this expression, \$V_p\$ represents the peak voltage of the pulse-width modulator (PWM) ramp (2 V in this example), \$V_{in}\$ is the input voltage and \$N\$ represents the transformer turns ratio \$1:N\$.

This dc gain is affected by all the ohmic losses, \$r_{DS(on)}\$, \$r_L\$ etc. which are considered zero here.

You could find many of these converters free templates from my [web page](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm). They all run on [Elements](https://www.simplistechnologies.com/product/elements) and will let you explore the transfer functions of these converters.

Now, based on the data-sheet, I would be inclined to think that the peak voltage is around 3.5 V or so because it corresponds to the maximum duty ratio value on one output:

[image]

which also corresponds to the clock amplitude if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: thank you for the answer sir, but what's the Vp: 2V here?

Comment: Hello, glad if this could help. \$V_p\$ is the peak voltage of the PWM ramp. It is 2 V in my example hence a 6-dB attenuation incurred by the modulator alone. If my interpretation of the 3525 data-sheet is correct, \$V_p\$ should be 3.5 V or so for this controller.